# How to connect rails 3.1.1 to webservice Amazon to get info of books

Tags: amazon-web-services, ruby-on-rails-3

I need to connect to Amazon WebServices to get the info of a book with the ISBN given by the user.

The problem is that I don`t know how to do this. I don´t have found any good documentation to do this in google. I have seen this article

http://aws.amazon.com/articles/846

but it doesn`t explain the steps to do this.

I am newby in rails. So, anybody can give tips to do this?

Which is the best gem to connect to Amazon WebServices with Rest? Or which is the best gem to attack to REST WebServices?
Which is exactly the name of the webservice of Amazon to get the info?
Do you know any article to do this?

Answer (score 1):

There's a couple of gems that can help your app interface with the Amazon API. The one I use at present is called amazon_product, and you can find it here: https://github.com/hakanensari/amazon_product/